# does php loads at most one php.ini, or are settings from higher-level php.ini inherited by more specific php.ini?

Tags: php

Does PHP interpreter loads first php.ini it finds (according to its search algorithm) and stops. Or does it load entire php.ini hierarchy and merges the settings?

So, if I need to overwrite single setting for a single web site - do I need to specify ALL values, or do I only need to specify values that are different from "higher-level" php.ini?

Comment: You can test it out using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: Depends on how your hosting is set up.

Comment: As far as I know with mine, is that when I created a `php.ini` file and placed it inside my `cgi-bin` which is where my host told me to put it in, is that it will override only the setting(s) you have in "your" file, therefore all other settings already set by your host, will and should theoretically remain untouched.

Comment: phpinfo does show loaded configuration file, but it does not answer whether that's the only file that's get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one file gets loaded and parsed. Check out the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_ini.c#L383). It basically builds `php_ini_scanned_path` and then `zend_parse_ini_string`s it. There's only one call to `zend_parse_ini_string` and one call to `php_init_config`.